# How do I remove part of a string from a specific character?

Tags: javascript

I have the following url:

```
http://intranet-something/IT/Pages/help.aspx?kb=1
```

I want to remove the `?kb=1` and assign `http://intranet-something/IT/Pages/help.aspx` to a new variable.

So far I've tried the following:

```
var link = "http://intranet-something/IT/Pages/help.aspx?kb=1"

if(link.includes('?kb=')){
  var splitLink = link.split('?');
}
```

However this just removes the question mark.

The 1 at the end of the url can change.

How do I remove everything from and including the question mark?

Comment: Did you mean to split `link` variable instead of `kbLink`?

Comment: Your code is correct, and url you want to get is under `splitLink[0]`

Comment: `'http://intranet-something/IT/Pages/help.aspx?kb=1'.split('?')[0]`

Comment: *"However this just removes the question mark.*" No, it doesn't. It splits at the separator and creates an array of the chunks. `splitLink` is an array and you need to take the first element using `splitLink[0]`

Comment: once check splitLink[0]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`URL`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) interface to manipulate URLs:

```js
const link = "http://intranet-something/IT/Pages/help.aspx?kb=1";
const url = new URL(link);
url.search = '';
console.log(url.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var link = "http://intranet-something/IT/Pages/help.aspx?kb=1"

if (link.includes('?kb=')) {
  var splitLink = link.split('?');
}

var url = splitLink ? splitLink[0] : link;

console.log(url);
```

Comment: This produces an error if `link` does *not* include "?kb="…

Answer (score 0):

```js
var link = "http://intranet-something/IT/Pages/help.aspx?kb=1"
if(link.includes('?kb=')){
  var splitLink = link.split('?');
  console.log(splitLink[0]);
}
```

Comment: @deanjmay your code is correct use  console.log(splitLink[0])

Answer (score 0):

**You can also try like this**

```js
const link = "http://intranet-something/IT/Pages/help.aspx?kb=1";
const NewLink = link.split('?');
console.log(NewLink[0]);
```